# Connecting Subscriptions and Start Trials on Branch.io with Facebook Ad Partner

Tags: branch.io, revenuecat

I'm trying to configure Facebook as an Ad Partner to import data such as subscriptions and start trials, but it seems like Branch.io only allow to map event such as Install and Opens.

[image]

Is there a way to import subscription data to Branch.io? I'm using RevenueCat for the subscriptions, but importing all the data on Facebook Ads as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make sure that the events are properly configured and getting ingested on your Branch dashboard.
Once we start ingesting the data and the numbers are populated, you would need to go to the Ads>Partner Management>Facebook > Event Config tab>Add event mapping and the event would show up on the 'Your event name' dropdown.
Post the above, you can map the same with your FB event of choice.

Please follow the documentation below to understand on how to record an event on the Branch dashboard : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/tracking-commerce-content-lifecycle-and-custom-events